# How can I achieve the Fox codename?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

I'm trying to unlock the "Fox" codename. According to [this source](http://segmentnext.com/2015/09/03/mgsv-phantom-pain-codenames-and-emblems-unlock-guide-how-to/), it should require:

```
You were not detected in the last three missions (does not count Reflex Mode as detection).
```

However, I cannot seem to unlock it. When I first started going for it, I kept unlocking the Foxhound codename instead. So, I started killing one enemy per run through, since that loses the Foxhound requirement - but then I started getting Octopus again.

Has anyone had any success getting this?  Any tips?

Comment: I checked my copy of the official guide and that requirement is verbatim form there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, I started killing one enemy per run through, since that loses the Foxhound requirement - but then I started getting Octopus again.

Well, stop tranqing people so much. It's really that simple. The game has a codename "priority" system. FOXHOUND is at the top because it is the best, so the game will always award you FOXHOUND if you meet the criteria. I would not have thought that Fox is at the same priority as Octopus, but it's not impossible.

Try to avoid using the tranquilizer and kill one or two enemies. Decoys are really effective if you have not been using those. Neutralize as few enemies as possible while still getting one or two to negate the FOXHOUND codename.

Comment: To emphasize this a bit: Using a tranquilizer weapon (or any silent nonlethal weapon) won't invalidate Perfect Stealth, No kills (the sole requirement for Foxhound). It's possible (very likely) that you've been using tranquilizers while getting Foxhound, so when you failed Perfect Stealth, No kills, the game looked at your neutralization history and saw the tranqs and gave you Octopus because of that.

Comment: Yeah, and following that logic, the Fox codename only has a Perfect Stealth requirement, which isn't that hard to get if you tranq everyone. However it seems that the game prioritizes Octopus if you get enough tranq neutralizations over Fox, or at least that's what I have to assume, so the solution is to have less neutralizations (or so I think) over the course of 3 missions.

Comment: Yup, I think you are completely right.  I was tranquillizing most enemies on those run throughs.  Funnily enough, I ended up playing [TRUTH] The Man Who Sold the World after doing those Foxhound runs, and earned Fox since you don't have the option to tranq/fulton anyone, hahahaha.  I guess before I was just surprised that Octopus was given priority over Fox.